# Flask - WSGI process keeps crashing

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I get strange errors when trying to deploy a Flask app (v0.8). I'm using apache's mod_wsgi, [as suggested in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache) (almost to the letter). What's strange is that on some requests (simply accessing `/` via browser), the application loads fine, but very often I get a resource load errors (can't fetch some css or image), and the error log shows something like `Premature end of script headers: myapp.wsgi`. Sometimes apache crashes with **Internal Server Error**. I'm trying to chase the problem but could not figure out what's the cause. My wsgi file looks simple:

```
from myapp import app as application
```

Any clues where to start looking?

Comment: Did you forget to remove an unconditional `app.run()` call?

Comment: Have you verified that you are not suffering from any of the issues described in the troubleshooting section of the docs? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#troubleshooting - if I were to guess, I'd say you were probably having issues with `print` calls + symlinking, given the combination of issues you are describing.  (Note that Apache is most likely not crashing when it returns a 500 - it's just handling the 500 error generated by `mod_wsgi` [which is in turn generated, most likely, by your application]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting Premature end of script headers, you are using daemon mode and the daemon process is crashing with a seg fault or similar.

Make sure you aren't still loading mod_python.

Also try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to work around issues with Python C extension modules which aren't safe for sub interpreters.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues

and look for various reasons for crashes listed.