# Why gevent on a Flask app with Apache + mod_wsgi is raising NotImplementedError?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, flask, gevent

I'm having an issue deploying my Flask app with Apache (mod_wsgi)
and gevent on a shared hosting (Webfaction).

The application works fine in the development server provided by Flask, but when I
try to deploy it I get the following error in log file:

```
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error]   File "evdns.pxi", line 78, in gevent.core.__evdns_callback (gevent/core.c:6300)
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error]   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/staging/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 297, in switch_args
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error]   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/staging/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 290, in switch
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error]   File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/staging/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 135, in get_hub
[Tue Mar 13 15:48:24 2012] [error] NotImplementedError: gevent is only usable from a single thread
```

I need gevent because I'm using the [python-requests' async module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests) to
make concurrent HTTP requests.
I tried to Google around but the only advice I found is to to call

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

something that I already do in my code.

The value of `WSGIDaemonProcess` is:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp processes=5 python-path=/home/myusername/webapps/myapp/lib/python2.7 threads=1
```

Here is my httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/eWygicJH

Anybody has any advice to solve this issue?

Comment: which is the value of WSGIDaemonProcess on your httpd.conf?

Comment: Could possibly be because gevent in my experience gets a bit upset if it only gets to monkey patch the Python threading module after someone else has already imported it and used it in certain ways. Is causing me no end of problems with some stuff. Haven't had a chance to delve into issue yet though.

Comment: @Masci I updated the question with a link to my httpd.conf and the value of WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: I noticed you're using python 2.7. I'm not shure monkeypatch trick works with this version, could you try with 2.6?

Comment: @Masci I will try switching to python 2.6, but I don't understand why this issue could be version specific.

Comment: @Raben sorry, I knew there were some issues with python 2.7 but they were fixed time ago so, except you're using a *very* old version of gevent, don't mind my advice above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like i found the solution myself. The following directive solved my issue:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

The idea comes from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961736/246242) where it is suggested to set WSGIApplicationGroup to GLOBAL to solve a problem with a WSGI process that keep crashing. [From WSGI documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues):

> To force a specific WSGI application to be run within the very first
>   Python sub interpreter created when Python is initialised, the
>   WSGIApplicationGroup directive should be used and the group set to
>   '%{GLOBAL}'.

Cannot fully understand why this directive solve my issue but it does. I will be more than happy if someone is able to explain this to me in plain English ;-)

Comment: please see [why-is-method-that-uses-gevent-in-a-mod-wsgi-deployed-flask-api-raising-error](http://serverfault.com/questions/754841/why-is-method-that-uses-gevent-in-a-mod-wsgi-deployed-flask-api-raising-error-ab) ... sorry to be so late to the game, but I finally have an answer.

Comment: Why -1 for this? The relevant answer to the question of "Cannot fully understand why this directive solve my issue but it does" is that "I found the answer here: Why does the directive WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} work for creating new threads

In a nutshell:

WSGIApplicationGroup: Set the execution to run under the same Python interpreter (the first created).
So, by default, each new thread must've not used the same python interpreter instance.

For uWSGI, the equivalent method is to add this to your .ini file:

single-interpreter = true"

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `monkey.patch_all()` with `monkey.patch_all(thread=False)`. If it's really the threading module which is causing the trouble when patched, this should solve it. `request` does not use threading.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I tried this solution but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I posted below answer on https://serverfault.com/a/869625/355861

apache mod_wsgi is not currently compatible with gevent. For AWS elastic beanstalk with Apache, I used async_mode="threading" for Flask and it works well. Note, threading has less performance than gevent.
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#deployment

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='static')
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="threading")
```

Note that Flask can run standalone with gevent.

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='static')
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="gevent") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 5055
    socketio.run(app, port=PORT, host=HOST)
```

However, you really want an HTTP server in front of it such as Gunicorn.