# Django gevent single thread error in Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, gevent

I'm importing a library with my code that gives me the

```
NotImplementedError: gevent is only usable from a single thread
```

the library is internal so I can't share it unfortunately.

I managed to solve this for the Django development server by adding:

```
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all(signal=False, httplib=False)
```

as the **first** two lines of my manage.py file after the shebang. Then I got to deploying it on apache with mod_wsgi and tought that it would be enough to have it as the first two lines of my wsgi.py-file. This was wrong. I think I've tried everything now, does anyone have any idea of what to do?!

Any ideas of a file that is executed before the wsgi.py file where I could try the monkey patch?

Comment: maybe this is helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/a/9710418/551760

Comment: No, already had that. It seems like it was caused by using libraries that instantiated both Gevent client and other client types which made Gevent complain as it didn't have enough control over the threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to solve this problem, but I managed to replace the two gevent client to other client types which made the problem go away...